# Where has my Python disappeared

Tags: python, macos

I had installed Python 2.7.6 via Macports on my Mac running OS X 10.9.2 and I recently uninstalled it and all its dependencies. My understanding is that I still have my Mac's original Python installed in /usr/bin as shown below:

```
Oliviers-iMac:~$ which -a python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
Oliviers-iMac:~$ python --version
-bash: /opt/local/bin/python: No such file or directory
Oliviers-iMac:~$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

What I don't understand is why doing a `python --version` doesn't show me the Python version that's installed on my Mac with OS X. Could someone kindly explain what I'm missing here. Do I have to change my $PATH or does it have something to do with symlinks that haven't been updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the you removed `python` installed in `/opt/local/bin`, and the shell still remember the path.

Issuing the following command will clear the cache:

```
hash -r
```

Then, try again `python --version`.

Comment: Excellent! That was a quick fix! Thank you. I suppose if I had opened a new Terminal window it would have also been fixed?

Comment: @Olivier, I think so because new terminal will create new a bash process.

Comment: (Another option might have been a symlink in `/opt/local/bin/` pointing "nowhere".)